# Post file from one MVC3 action to another site

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, post, httpwebrequest, multipartform-data

This might sound crazy, but I have an MVC3 action (server-side code) that needs to post a file to another web site. I have control over both sites, but the second site never receives the posted file data. I use WebRequest to successfully request a file from the remote site, so I figured I could post the file data using this approach:

```
private WebRequest _SetupCopyToRequest(string source, string expectedDestination)
{
    var request = HttpWebRequest.Create(_Settings.CopyToServerUrl);
    var info = new FileInfo(source);
    request.Method = "POST";
    request.ContentLength = info.Length;
    request.ContentType = "multipart/form-data";
    var dispositionValue = String.Format("form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"{0}\"", expectedDestination);
    request.Headers.Set("Content-Disposition", dispositionValue);
    using (var destStream = request.GetRequestStream())
    {
        using (var sourceStream = info.OpenRead())
        {
            var length = (int) info.Length;
            var buffer = new byte[info.Length];
            sourceStream.Read(buffer, 0, length);
            destStream.Write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
    }
    return request;
}
```

My problem is that the action on the receiving site receives the request as soon I call `request.GetRequestStream()` on the first site, and Request.Files is empty on the second site. Here is the code for the receiving action on the second site:

```
[HttpPost]                                                           
public ActionResult CopyToServer()
{
    if (Request.Files.Count == 0 || Request.Files[0].ContentLength == 0)
        return new ContentResult();

    var file = Request.Files[0];
    var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
    var directory = Path.GetDirectoryName(file.FileName);
    var uniqueFileName = CeoPath.GetUniqueFileName(directory, fileName);
    var path = Path.Combine(directory, uniqueFileName);
    file.SaveAs(path);
    return new ContentResult {Content = path};
}
```

So how do I get my file data from the first site's server posted to the second site's server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my answer by searching SO for HttpWebRequest and came across this one on [Upload files with HttpWebRequest (multipart/form-data)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/566462/upload-files-with-httpwebrequest-multipart-form-data). Especially the link to [Upload files using an RFC 1867 POST request with HttpWebRequest/WebClient](http://aspnetupload.com/Upload-File-POST-HttpWebRequest-WebClient-RFC-1867.aspx). So I just replaced my first method with the following working code:

```
public string CopyToServer(string source, string expectedDestination)
{
    var file = new UploadFile(source, "file", null);
    var form = new NameValueCollection();
    form["expectedFileName"] = expectedDestination;
    var request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(_Settings.CopyToServerUrl);
    var response = HttpUploadHelper.Upload(request, new[] {file}, form);
    using (var s = response.GetResponseStream())
    {
        using (var sr = new StreamReader(s))
        {
            return sr.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
}
```

Hurrah!

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `multipart/form-data` encoding for uploading files. For a single file upload you could use the [`UploadFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.uploadfile.aspx) method or I have blogged about a technique allowing you to [`upload multiple files`](http://www.bratched.com/en/home/dotnet/69-uploading-multiple-files-with-c.html).

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that your content-type is messing things up - you're declaring that you're sending multipart form-data, but I don't see where you do proper multipart encoding:

http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.2